# Network notification balloon stays showed too long

Tags: networking, notification

I'd like to know if there is a possibility and where can I adjust the network state notification balloon timer? Actually, if the computer is connected or disconnected to the network, the notification balloon will appear in the upper right corner of the workspace and stay there for approximately 9 seconds. If mouse cursor (accidentally) touch the notification balloon, it will stay showed for more than 9 seconds, which is quite annoying. Is there a possibility to manually adjust the timer and set it to 2 seconds? Personally, I think that it's enough.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adjust the notifications globally with **NotifyOSD**. Install it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

Then run it from *Accessories > NotifyOSD Configuration*

You can modify color, timeout, icon size or opacity